# Where is my picture?

Tags: support

I uploaded a picture of my mug last week to gravatar, and while my picture shows up in my personal profile, it doesn't show up next to my name on questions and answers.  It did for a while immediately after uploading, but then it disappeared.  I'm just wondering what's up.

Comment: Hmm...fwiw, I see it right here.  A quick check of some of your Q's and A's shows it too.  Perhaps your browser needs a cache refreshed?

Comment: [Gravatar](http://en.gravatar.com/) could be having delivery issues in your location - just give it a bit of time to fix itself.

Comment: @whuber Cleared the cache, then I tried IE.  nothin'.

Comment: @JarrodDixon That sounds plausible.  Thanks for the prompt response.